# How would i make my project search a database and return results to table

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, reactjs, jsx

I have a project where I need React Js to search a mssql database for a specific query and then return the results

[image: Left is the Form and on the right is where i want the data to be pushed to]

Left is the Form and on the right is where i want the data to be pushed to, they are in different jsx files so i would need to put the returned data from the database into an array const and pass it up to the parent and back down to the right box child

how would i go about doing this

code for left box

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import TextInput from '../SmallBits/FormItems/TextInput';

export default class LeftBox extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            forename: '',
            surname: '',
            caseID: '',
            address: ''
        }
        this.handleSurnameChange = this.handleSurnameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleForenameChange = this.handleForenameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleCaseIDChange = this.handleCaseIDChange.bind(this);
        this.handleAddressChange = this.handleAddressChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSurnameChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ surname: e.target.value });
    }
    handleForenameChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ forename: e.target.value });
    }
    handleCaseIDChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ caseID: e.target.value });
    }
    handleAddressChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ address: e.target.value });
    }
    handleFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formPayload = {
            name: this.state.surname,
            forename: this.state.forename
        };
        console.log('Send this in a POST request:', formPayload);
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 well-mod well-lg">
                    <form>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div className="col-md-5">
                                    <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>{nbsp}Forename</span>
                                    <TextInput className="form-control" inputType={'text'} name={'Forename'} controlFunc={this.handleForenameChange} content={this.state.forename} placeholder={'Enter Forename'} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div className="col-md-5">
                                    <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>{nbsp}Surname</span>
                                    <TextInput className="form-control" inputType={'text'} name={'Surname'} controlFunc={this.handleSurnameChange} content={this.state.surname} placeholder={'Enter Surname'} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div className="col-md-5">
                                    <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>{nbsp}Case ID</span>
                                    <TextInput className="form-control" inputType={'number'} name={'CaseID'} controlFunc={this.handleCaseIDChange} content={this.state.caseID} placeholder={'Enter Case ID'} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div className="col-md-5">
                                    <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>{nbsp}Email Address</span>
                                    <TextInput className="form-control" inputType={'text'} name={'Address'} controlFunc={this.handleAddressChange} content={this.state.address} placeholder={'Enter Email Address'} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div className="col-md-5">
                                <button className="btn btn-sm btn-success navbar-btn pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-search">&nbsp;Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code for right box

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class RightBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 well-mod well-lg">
                <p>This is the Right Box</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

main content code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import LeftBox from '../Boxes/LeftBox';
import RightBox from '../Boxes/RightBox';

import '../../../styles/Cust.css';

export default class MainContent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ModContainer">
          <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="col-md-7">
                  <LeftBox />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-1-mod">

              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                  <RightBox />
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

code for text input

```
import React from 'react';

const InputHeight = {
    height:'50px',
}

const TextInput = (props) => (
    <div className="form-group">
        <input
            className="form-control"
            name={props.name}
            type={props.inputType}
            value={props.content}
            onChange={props.controlFunc}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            style={InputHeight}
            required />
    </div>
);

TextInput.propTypes = {
    inputType: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['text', 'number',     'email']).isRequired,
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    controlFunc: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    content: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
        React.PropTypes.string,
        React.PropTypes.number,
    ]).isRequired,
    placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
};

export default TextInput;
```

i am going to be putting a layer of C# for the backend before the sql so that is what i am looking for what would i do to connect this search button to the C# backend.

I would love help on this please I would be so grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# backend need to provide an API endpoint. For example you will define a route `/api/search` that accepts a query parameter object and returns the result in JSON format.

On the frontend you will have to make an HTTP request to your backend to retrieve the result based on the query.

Your MainComponent will be responsible for calling the API and feed your RightBox with the result.